# Canvas not scaling correctly in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-canvas

I'm trying to use an html canvas in a React.js app to allow users to draw using their mouse. However, the strokes appear to be zoomed in and the positioning is off by some factor (not a constant) such that in the top left corner it is fairly accurate, but as the mouse is moved across the canvas the stroke moves much faster (or farther) than the mouse. The canvas is as such:

```
  <div>
    <canvas className={classes.canvas} ref={this.canvas} />
  </div>
```

with the following styling (using material-ui withStyles):

```
const styles = {
  canvas: {
    width: "400px",
    height: "400px",
    border: "2px solid black",
    borderRadius: "5px"
  },
  container: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%"
  }
}
```

The event listeners are set up in componentDidMount:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = this.canvas.current;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
    this.setState({
      ctx,
      offsetX: canvas.offsetLeft,
      offsetY: canvas.offsetTop
    });
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleMouseDown);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", this.handleMouseUp);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseleave", this.handleMouseUp);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", this.handleMouseMove);
  }
```

The handlers are as follows:

```
  handleMouseDown = e => {
    const { ctx, offsetX, offsetY } = this.state;
    const x = e.clientX - offsetX;
    const y = e.clientY - offsetY;
    this.setState({ isDrawing: true });
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  };

  handleMouseUp = e => {
    this.setState({ isDrawing: false });
    const { ctx } = this.state;
    ctx.closePath();
  };

  handleMouseMove = e => {
    if (this.state.isDrawing) {
      const { ctx, offsetX, offsetY } = this.state;
      console.log("offset", offsetX, offsetY);
      const x = e.clientX - offsetX;
      const y = e.clientY - offsetY;
      console.log("client", x, y);
      ctx.lineTo(x, y);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  };
```

Here's a screenshot of the canvas after drawing a line starting from the top left corner (with the approximate mouse position add in):
[image: Screenshot of canvas drawing with approximate mouse position. Started from top left corner]

UPDATE: Tried using `canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left and .top`, which actually made it worse. I also tried to scale down by using `ctx.scale(0.5, 0.5)` before drawing, but this made no change at all.

Comment: The CSS rules for `canvas.style.width` and `canvas.style.height` set the display size. Display size is independent of the canvas resolution which is set via the `canvas.width` and `canvas.height` attribute. You have not set the canvas resolution so it has defaulted to 300 by 150. In JS set the canvas res to match the style. eg `canvas.width = 400;` `canvas.height = 400;`